# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 828 path $.data.user.agent.identity_type

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

```
package com.cico.cicocashincashout.model.login.response;


import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Agent {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("date_of_birth")
@Expose
private String dateOfBirth;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
private String gender;
@SerializedName("business_name")
@Expose
private String businessName;
@SerializedName("business_address")
@Expose
private String businessAddress;
@SerializedName("business_phone")
@Expose
private String businessPhone;
@SerializedName("state_id")
@Expose
private Integer stateId;
@SerializedName("local_government_id")
@Expose
private Integer localGovernmentId;
@SerializedName("account_number")
@Expose
private String accountNumber;
@SerializedName("account_name")
@Expose
private String accountName;
@SerializedName("bank_id")
@Expose
private Integer bankId;
@SerializedName("bvn")
@Expose
private String bvn;
@SerializedName("agent_code")
@Expose
private String agentCode;
@SerializedName("identity_type")
@Expose
private Terminal identityType;
@SerializedName("business_type")
@Expose
private String businessType;
@SerializedName("super_agent_id")
@Expose
private Terminal superAgentId;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("wallet_no")
@Expose
private String walletNo;
@SerializedName("terminal_id")
@Expose
private Terminal terminalId;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updatedAt;
@SerializedName("activation_code")
@Expose
private String activationCode;
@SerializedName("bank_code")
@Expose
private String bankCode;
@SerializedName("uuid")
@Expose
private String uuid;
@SerializedName("api_key")
@Expose
private String apiKey;
@SerializedName("commission_value")
@Expose
private Terminal commissionValue;
@SerializedName("webhook")
@Expose
private Terminal webhook;
@SerializedName("full_name")
@Expose
private String fullName;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getBusinessName() {
    return businessName;
}

public void setBusinessName(String businessName) {
    this.businessName = businessName;
}

public String getBusinessAddress() {
    return businessAddress;
}

public void setBusinessAddress(String businessAddress) {
    this.businessAddress = businessAddress;
}

public String getBusinessPhone() {
    return businessPhone;
}

public void setBusinessPhone(String businessPhone) {
    this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
}

public Integer getStateId() {
    return stateId;
}

public void setStateId(Integer stateId) {
    this.stateId = stateId;
}

public Integer getLocalGovernmentId() {
    return localGovernmentId;
}

public void setLocalGovernmentId(Integer localGovernmentId) {
    this.localGovernmentId = localGovernmentId;
}

public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

public Integer getBankId() {
    return bankId;
}

public void setBankId(Integer bankId) {
    this.bankId = bankId;
}

public String getBvn() {
    return bvn;
}

public void setBvn(String bvn) {
    this.bvn = bvn;
}

public String getAgentCode() {
    return agentCode;
}

public void setAgentCode(String agentCode) {
    this.agentCode = agentCode;
}

public Terminal getIdentityType() {
    return identityType;
}

public void setIdentityType(Terminal identityType) {
    this.identityType = identityType;
}

public String getBusinessType() {
    return businessType;
}

public void setBusinessType(String businessType) {
    this.businessType = businessType;
}

public Terminal getSuperAgentId() {
    return superAgentId;
}

public void setSuperAgentId(Terminal superAgentId) {
    this.superAgentId = superAgentId;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getWalletNo() {
    return walletNo;
}

public void setWalletNo(String walletNo) {
    this.walletNo = walletNo;
}

public Terminal getTerminalId() {
    return terminalId;
}

public void setTerminalId(Terminal terminalId) {
    this.terminalId = terminalId;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public String getActivationCode() {
    return activationCode;
}

public void setActivationCode(String activationCode) {
    this.activationCode = activationCode;
}

public String getBankCode() {
    return bankCode;
}

public void setBankCode(String bankCode) {
    this.bankCode = bankCode;
}

public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public String getApiKey() {
    return apiKey;
}

public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
}

public Terminal getCommissionValue() {
    return commissionValue;
}

public void setCommissionValue(Terminal commissionValue) {
    this.commissionValue = commissionValue;
}

public Terminal getWebhook() {
    return webhook;
}

public void setWebhook(Terminal webhook) {
    this.webhook = webhook;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}


}
```

from the response, identity type is actually a string, I really don't know where I am getting it wrong

```
"identity_type": "driver's license",
```

Comment: you get "identity_type": "driver's license" from your response?

Comment: yes, I also forgot to add this   "agent_code": "XT/B/AA/29664525"

Comment: What is `Terminal`, and why do you believe the *string* value `"driver's license"` will parse into a `Terminal` *object*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned identity_type is an `object` but you are receiving a `string`

```
@SerializedName("identity_type")
@Expose
private Terminal identityType;
```

Change `Terminal` to `String` it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `identity_type` is coming as `String` but you have declared as `Terminal`.

Change from

```
@SerializedName("identity_type")
@Expose
private Terminal identityType;
```

**To**

```
@SerializedName("identity_type")
@Expose
private String identityType;
```

Hope this will help you.